# Anyone tried building kernel for Redmi Note 12 Pro 5g Ruby?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel, xiaomi

I'm compiling kernels to compile wifi driver for kali nethunter but I'm failing constantly, i don't even know the kernel source I'm using is legit or not.

Kernel sorce : https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/tree/ruby-s-oss

https://github.com/Coconutat/android_kernel_xiaomi_ruby_exp

https://github.com/Mayuri-Chan/android_kernel_xiaomi_ruby

My device: Redmi Note 12 Pro 5G (codename_ruby)

I tried compiling it by looking at YouTube videos got few errors at start i resolved them.

But now i don't know what to do

Here is my error output:

In file included from kernel/sched/tune.c:11: kernel/sched/sched.h: In function ‘alloc_uclamp_sched_group’:                      kernel/sched/sched.h:2365:13: error: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’ ‘uclamp_se_set’: function body not available 2365 | inline void uclamp_se_set(struct uclamp_se *uc_se, |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                  kernel/sched/tune.c:573:17: note: called from here 573 |                 uclamp_se_set(&st->uclamp_req[clamp_id], |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 574 |                               uclamp_none(clamp_id), false); |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ kernel/sched/sched.h:2365:13: error: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’ ‘uclamp_se_set’: function body not available 2365 | inline void uclamp_se_set(struct uclamp_se *uc_se, |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ kernel/sched/tune.c:573:17: note: called from here                                   573 |                 uclamp_se_set(&st->uclamp_req[clamp_id], |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 574 |                               uclamp_none(clamp_id), false); |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ At top level: cc1: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:334: kernel/sched/tune.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:637: kernel/sched] Error 2                    make: *** [Makefile:1172: kernel] Error 2